# If attribute = 'yes' then show this html, if attribute = 'no' show this html

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4

I have an attribute called 'made_to_order' and it has a dropdown select (in the backend of Magento) with two outcomes 'yes' or 'no'. At the moment I'm just echoing the yes or no on the frontend. However, ideally I'd like to show different html dependent on the attribute value. For example, if 'yes' then green color font, if 'no' then red color font.

Can anyone please help with the code for this? My current code is:

```
 <p style="font-size: 1.1em;line-height:1.2em;"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('made_to_order') ?></p>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('made_to_order') == $this->__('yes')): ?>
      <p class="made_to_order_yes"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('made_to_order') ?></p>
<?php else; ?>
     <p class="made_to_order_no"><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('made_to_order') ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, if I had multiple options for one attribute I guess I would continue to extend the if statement....?

Comment: Yes... using `elseif ($_product->getAttributeText('made_to_order') == $this->__('xyz')):` ..See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magento 1.9 and this code works for me

```
<?php if($_product->getData(" --attribute name-- ")==1)
{
}
else
{
}
?>
```